# SQL Server : run query on server instead of local computer

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I think this should be simple but I cannot really find a way to do it. I have some devs connecting to a remote SQL Server 2017 using SQL Server Management Studio. Sometimes they need to run queries that take several hours to complete.

However, their laptops go to sleep if they leave them overnight which sometimes breaks the process. I do not want them to RDP to the server. Is there a way (without server/SQL admin intervention) for their queries to run persistently on the server instead of their local laptops?

I know, they could just set up their laptops to just do not go to sleep. However, that is a security policy in the company and it is a huge pain in the butt to ask for a laptop to be excluded from it.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: SQL agent jobs?

Comment: Don't let them go to sleep but do require that the screen locks after some period of inactivity (or when they leave).

Comment: Hi @dfundako.  I have no idea, I will look into that. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @SMor.  The policies are not up to me. No easy to change them. Thanks.

Comment: [Similar question on dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/273627/disconnect-from-network-without-stopping-the-query).

Answer (score 0):

What kind of database is it? For example... If an MS SQL Server then you can use an SQL Server Agent which run scheduled jobs (with tasks). Is it Azure? Then use an Elastic Job. Figure that out first before you waste your time looking into a tool that is not right for your database.